# PHP OOP-based login system

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I am building an OOP-based user authentication system, and I would like to incorporate the following principles: Direct Injection, Inheritance, Encapsulation, Polymorphism and the Single Responsibility Principle.

My background in programming is has always relied on procedural programming, and thus, am finding it difficult to really put these practices into ***correct*** use.

Assume I have these classes:

```
class Config
{
    public function set($key, $value);
    public function get($key, $default = null);
}

class User
{
    public function __construct(PDO $dbh, $id = null);
    public function setProfile(Profile $profile);
}

class Auth
{
    public function __construct(Config $config);
    public function login($username, $password, $keepLoggedIn = true);
    public function isLoggedIn();
    public function getLoggedInUser();
    public function logout();
    public function register(array $data);
}

class Session
{
    public function start($sessionName = null);
    public function write($key, $value);
    public function read($key, $default = null);
}

class Profile
{
    public function setAddress(Address $address);
    public function setName($name);
    public function setDOB(DateTime $date);
    public function getAge();
}

class Validator
{
    public function validate($input);
}
```

I have intentionally left off the function bodies to keep things simple.

To the best of my knowledge, I believe I'm using the principles correctly. However, I am still unclear as to how you would connect classes like: the `Validator` to the `User` model, the `User` model to the `Auth` and the `Session` to the `Auth` class. All of which depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The way these classes connect to each other is called extending. I tend to go towards an MVC setup, meaning **M**odel, **V**iew, **C**ontroller.

Your logic goes into the controller, all your DB queries and concrete back end methods go in the model. The controller receives requests and returns responses. It's the middleman. It talks to the back end after a request has been made to it, and feeds the front in via response.

So you have a core controller (keep it bare minimal), then each class you make extends the core controller. So your controller is where you tie all this together.

```
 <?php
//your main core controller, where you load all these things you need avilable, so long as this class is extended
class CoreController {

    public $auth
    public $session;
    public $view;

   function construct__ ()
   {
       $this->auth = instantiateAuthClassHere();
       $this->session = instantiateSessionClassHere();
       $this->view = instantiateViewClassHere();
   }

    public function anotherHelperForSomething(){
        //helper stuff for this method    
    }
}

//index, page, or content controller, depending on how many you need, i.e. if you want a controller for each page, thats fine, e.g indexController, etc..
//this is the middle man, has logic, receives requst, returns response to view.
class Controller extends CoreController {

    public function index (){

        $userModel = new userModel();

        //do something with this
        $session = $this->session;

        $content = 'some html';
        $userInfo = $userModel->getUsers();

        $view = $this->view->render( array(
            'content' => $content,
            'userInfo' => $userInfo,
        ));

        return $view;
    }
}

//Core LIbraries
class Validator {
    //your validator stuff
}

//Core LIbraries
class Session {
    //your validator stuff
}

//Core LIbraries
class Auth {
    //your validator stuff
}

class CoreModel{

    public $validator;

    function __construct(){
        $this->validator = instantiateValidatorClassHere();
    }
}

//a user model  class (back end). you want a model class for each db table pretty much. 
class UserModel extends CoreModel {


// if you need the validator anywhere inside this class, its globally available here inside any class that extends the CoreModel, e.g.  $this->validator->methodName()


    public function getUsers (){
        $sql = 'SELECT * from users';
        $result = $db->get($sql);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Notice, on the `Controller`, this is a generic name for something like `indexController`, or anything custom. Also, I have the word `extends` there. It inherits all the objects from the parent that it extends. Inside it, now they will be available via `$this->`. See my example where I get `$this->session`.

Try to avoid constructs - you probably don't need them anywhere except for the core, and under special circumstances, which you might then need to check for yourself before you do even that. I dont use constructs much anymore. It can be a bit clunky and unmanageable.

Comment: I like this pattern it simplifies things significantly, but what about the Model? The Model is responsible for validating it's own data.

Comment: hi, i added the model in there, on an edit..  ok, i think i see you have a need for the validate class in teh model, not the index controller, so we can also make a core model controller how would that be?  ok, i updated that..

Comment: Hey, from my point of view, using the MVC pattern would prevent classes from being reused. For example, moving validation logic for the `User` model into the controller, would also mean I cannot ever reuse the model outside of my application and even to a certain extent, inside my own application.

Comment: well, the model is only for your application, not another.  this is the applications model..   yes it prevents classes from being rewritten..  yes validation logic for user prob should go in controller, not model. good thinking, your on the correct track.  think of it like a business model, only for one buiness.

Comment: by the way, your core libraries that i have above, dont fit into the m, v, or c, they are just outside 3rd party libraries, that you extend.   in symfony they are called vendors.  think of these core-libraries classes that your going to use as your vendors, and not part of your MVC.  so you can have a directory structure, like site/app/model/, site/app/views/app/controller/ site/vendors/ValidationClassVendorName/ValidationController.php for e.g,

Comment: correction from above, site/app/model/, site/app/views/, site/app/controller, site/vendors/VendorName/VendorController.php then you can either include these vendors in your core controller, or even better use autoload and namespacing (another topic).  By the way if this was helpful, can you mark it as accepted answer please?

Comment: This is actually making things easier now it would seem that my libraries would be `Config`, `Session` and `Validator`; my models would be `Profile`, `Address` and `User`; and my previously stated `Auth` class would in fact be an `AuthController` with `login`, `register` and `logout` actions. Does this sound right?

Comment: not auth controller, but try UserController, AddressController, and ProfileController instead, put all your controller logic here for each of thse, using the validation here.  no need for AuthCOntroller, that will sit inside the vendors folder, and be instantiated on the CoreController, and used inside your model controllers essentially.  so i failed to mention, that for each Model, you want an equally named controller...  e.g. model/UserModel.php and controller/UserController.php sweet huh?

Comment: ok, i also may have mistated something, your libraries being Config, Session, and Validator only are libraries, e.g. vendors, if your downloading this code from elsewhere, if your implementing it, then just puit your OWN model/SessionModel.php , instead of downloading 3rd party and placing inside vendor/Somebody/Session.php  So i think this would be a good example of something else besides DB stuff, that goes on the model.  Once you implement this session controller, its just your  sesino controller, so its part of your model in this case,

Comment: ...because it will never change, and not likely to be alot of logic on it..  so aare you using 3rd party stuff for these libraries or was this just my bad assumption?  and im conflicted if so, maybe somebody else has an opinion on wether the Session would be a model, or controller.   I can easily see it going inside controller/SessionController.php, and be instantiated on CoreController.php like i already mentioned.

Comment: I was just using these classes as examples. I have libraries that I would prefer to use instead (why re-invent the wheel). Thanks for your help.

Comment: i just thought of one more idea, you know what would make this a good topic if you changed teh question title to something like PHP Procedural to MVC OOP theory basics. or soemting of the sort.. you take a guess, but i always like to reedit my title after the questino has been answered so it will be easier found by other users.

Comment: note, i made an edit, forgot to add the public property on the CoreModel its there now

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC and neither does OPs question. Also you are tightly coupling everything in your classes by instantiating everything inside the classes. You loose encapsulation by making everything `public`. Your GodModeController instantiates things it might not even need. Your comment about "Try to avoid constructs" makes no sense whatsoever. I feel bad for @NathanBishop that he thinks this answer will actually make his code better in some way.

Comment: wow.. notice, he is getting into OOP, from procedural. this is a great start, and gets him the concept nicely. there is nothing wrong with passing around needed objects, its what an application is for. I disagree with the tightly-coupling here, you only call what you need, and keep everything private possible, protected when not, and public otherwise. i suggest making most properties private, however that introduces more complexity to an answer that i was trying to keep semi generic.  notice, i only instantiated the model when i needed it for example, not inside a god-mode controller.

Comment: I made an edit my answer, i forgot to remove the validator property from the core controller, i already had it in the coremodel. I dont know if thats one source of confusion.  by the way, this is pretty much the way alot of frameworks work, kohana, symnfony.... What did you mean not MVC?